# How does the Amass intel module correlate information?

Tags: dns-domain, information-gathering, reconnaissance

Can someone explain to me how [OWASP Amass](https://github.com/OWASP/Amass) correlates information regarding the intel module domain search?

As an example, if I run the command:

`amass intel -d example.com -whois`

I'll get a list of domains related to `example.com`.

How are all domains related? How does amass search for the related domains in the intel module?

Comment: You've read the documentation? https://github.com/OWASP/Amass/blob/master/doc/user_guide.md#the-intel-subcommand Do you know what "reverse whois" is?

Comment: @schroeder I was looking for a more indepth explanation than the one provided by amass documentation, therefrom I made this post...

Comment: Ok, but explaining what you ***do*** know helps to prevent people from just linking to the documentation ...

Comment: And, have you noticed that I provided a link to the source code where you can see, definitively, what the `intel` module does? (check out the comments in the code if you are having trouble interpreting the code itself.)